# Poor performance for SVM for unbalanced dataset- how to improve?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

Consider a dataset `A` which has examples for training in a binary classification problem. I have used SVM and applied the weighted method (in MATLAB) since the dataset is highly imbalanced. I have applied weights as inversely proportional to the frequency of data in each class. This is done on training using the command

```
 fitcsvm(trainA, trainTarg , ...
            'KernelFunction', 'RBF', 'KernelScale', 'auto', ...
            'BoxConstraint', C,'Weight',weightTrain  );
```

I have used 10 folds cross-validation for training and learned the hyperparameter as well. so, inside CV the dataset `A` is split into train (`trainA`) and validation sets (`valA`). After training is over and outside the CV loop, I get the confusion matrix on `A`:

```
80025 1
0 140
```

where the first row is for the majority class and the second row is for the minority class. There is only 1 false positive (FP) and all minority class examples have been correctly classified giving true positive (TP) = 140.

**PROBLEM**: Then, I  run the trained model on a new unseen test data set `B` which was never seen during training. This is the confusion matrix for testing on `B` .

```
50075 0
100 0
```

As can be seen, the minority class has not been classified at all, hence the purpose of weights has failed. Although, there is no FP the SVM fails to capture the minority class examples.
I have not applied any weights or balancing method such as sampling (SMOTE, RUSBoost etc) on `B`. What could be wrong and how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class misclassification weights could be set instead of sample weights!

You can set the class weights based on the following example.

Mis-classification weight for class A(n-records; dominant) into class B (m-records; minority class) can be n/m. 
Mis-classification weight For class B as class A can be set as 1 or m/n based on the severity, which you want to impose on the learning

```
c=[0 2.2;1 0];
mod=fitcsvm(X,Y,'Cost',c)
```

According to [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html):

> For two-class learning, if you specify a cost matrix, then the
>   software updates the prior probabilities by incorporating the
>   penalties described in the cost matrix. Consequently, the cost matrix
>   resets to the default. For more details on the relationships and
>   algorithmic behavior of BoxConstraint, Cost, Prior, Standardize, and
>   Weights, see Algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How did you come up with the numbers in the cost matrix? Can you kindly elaborate a bit more -- what the rows and columns indicate?

Comment: Diagonal values are going to be zero, because it is correctly classified datapoints. off-diagonal ones based on the penalty you would like to give for class i (row i) being classified as class j (column j)

Comment: Ok, thanks again for your reply. So, in my case the minority class is the second row and that is of interest to me. You mentioned to decide the weights as inversely proportional to freq of the class. Therefore, how did you come up with the numbers is still unclear

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just to clarify 2 points: (1) in my case as I am interested in the minority class and by looking at the first confusion matrix in my Question, the cost matrix should be `[0,1; m/n, 0]`? (2) Is it necessary that the training set = independent test set in order for the class frequencies to remain similar? Shall really appreciate if you can pls clarify these

Comment: 1- i think, it is right. Kindly try the other combination as well. 2- having a similar frequencies would be useful in measuring the performance of the model. Hence, Better to use stratified splitting.

Answer (score 1):

[Area Under Curve (AUC)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it) is usually used to measure performance of models that applied on unbalanced data. It is also good to plot ROC curve to visually get more insights. Using only confusion matrix for such models may lead to misinterpretation.

[`perfcurve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html) from the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox provides both functionalities.